# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable - when attempting to add additional attribute into python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, append

I'm trying to append python list with two values returned as json within `data` into my `final_list` .

My code:

```
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    final_list = []
    for each_req in data:
        final_list.append(each_req(['requestId'],['author']))
    return final_list
```

Error:

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

If I try the same but only with `requestId` it works fine:

```
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    final_list = []
    for each_req in data:
        final_list.append(each_req['requestId'])
    return final_list
```

list then contains values like '12345' etc.

How can I append final_list to look like:

> '12345 John Doe'

Answer (score 3):

Do something like:

```py
tup = (each_req['requestId'], each_req['author'])
final_list.append(tup)
```

`each_req()` implies that it's a function and/or callable in some way, which it's not, hence the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the dictionary again to append the value to the list.

Try this:

```
final_list.append(each_req['requestId'] + each_req['author'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not given what type of data is coming,assuming that your
data is like  data = {'key1':{'requestId':12345,'author':'Myname'}}
for i in 'data' returns the 'keys' in dictionary and i['key1'] will not the value
of that key

then try this code

```
def foo():
    data = {'key1':{'requestId':12345,'author':'Myname'}}
    final_list = []
    for each_req in data:
        final_list.append(f"{data[each_req]['requestId']} {data[each_req]['author']}")
    return final_list

print(foo())
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
final_list.append(each_req['requestId'], each_req['author'])
```